# How to combine code in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple code which take a user from a file if the user exist in file it open a location of that file if login credentials mathched within the file but i am unable to do so the same through tkinter so far i have done this

```
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter.messagebox as tm 
import os

class LoginFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.label_1 = Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_2 = Label(self, text="Password")

        self.entry_1 = Entry(self)
        self.entry_2 = Entry(self, show="*")

        self.label_1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        self.label_2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.logbtn = Button(self, text="Login", command = self._login_btn_clickked)
        self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)

        self.pack()

    def _login_btn_clickked(self):
        #print("Clicked")
        username = self.entry_1.get()
        password = self.entry_2.get()

        #print(username, password)
        f = open("User.txt", "r")
        for line in f.readlines():
            us, pw = line.strip().split("|")
        if (username in us) and (password in pw==password):
            print ("Login successful!")
            f.close()
            return True
            print ("Wrong username/password")
            f.close()
            return False
    def menu():
    #here's a menu that the user can access if he logged in.
         users = []
         f = open("User.txt", "r")
         for line in f.readlines():
            us,pw = line.strip().split("|")
            users.append(us)
         for i in users:
            if (user == i):
             os.startfile("F:\waleed") '''
        if user=="malik":
         os.system('xdg-open "/home/pi/Desktop/malik"')
        if user=="john":
         os.system('xdg-open "/home/pi/Desktop/john"')
        '''   




        #here's a menu that the user can access if he logged in.


root = Tk() 
lf = LoginFrame(root)  
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code has several problems that have nothing to do with tkinter; it's not even valid python (at to the triple-quoted string). Narrow down your question to one problem to get useful help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `User.txt` file looks something like this (including this into your question would have been a good idea):

```
username_1|password1
username_2|password2
```

You don't have to use the `in` operator in this case. The `in` operator returns `True` if an element is contained in a container, e.g.:

```
"b" in "abc"  # returns True
"z" in "abc"  # returns False
```

In your case, you can just compare if username and password match exactly (using `==`) for each line in your `User.txt` file.

Applying this change and using a context manager for opening and closing the file, the `_login_btn_clickked()` method could look something like this:

```
def _login_btn_clickked(self):
    username = self.entry_1.get()
    password = self.entry_2.get()

    with open("User.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            us, pw = line.strip().split("|")
            if us == username and pw == password:
                print ("Login successful!")
                return True
```